# Error as "String index out of range: -1" with set keyword in Karate

Tags: karate

Below is the code snippet for which I am getting an error.

```
* def json = {"test" : { "data.a":'value',"data.b":'value2' }}
* print json.test["data.a"] // This line is working getting value 'value'
* set json.tes["data.a"] = 'hello' // This line is failing with error "String index out of range: -1

Response:
 [java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils.setValueByPath(JsonUtils.java:257)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.setValueByPath(Script.java:1519)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.setValueByPath(Script.java:1489)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.setValueByPath(Script.java:1479)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.setNamedByPath(StepDefs.java:572)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.setByPath(StepDefs.java:562)
    at ✽.* set json.tes["data.a"] = 'hello' // This line is failing with error "String index out of range: -1
```

Not able to set value for "data.a" dynamically using SET keyword.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be very badly designed JSON. Make a small change, use [`eval`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#eval):

```
* eval json.test["data.a"] = 'hello'
```